# Converting .docx to .pdf using Gotenberg and Google Cloud

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, gotenberg

As many here I stumbled across converting .docx to .pdf. The only reasonable solution out there seems to be [Gotenberg](https://thecodingmachine.github.io/gotenberg/) which is a Docker-powered stateless API and [Gotenberg js client](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gotenberg-js-client) which allows to interact with Gotenberg much easier through JS interface.

To use JS client we need to define Gotenberg's Docker-powered address:

```js
import { pipe, gotenberg, convert, html, please } from 'gotenberg-js-client'

const toPDF = pipe(
  gotenberg('http://localhost:3000'), <--- here
  convert,
  html,
  please
)
```

I'm no wizard of JS nor client-side nor backend so I want to ask you guys: how (if possible) I could implement it using Google Cloud solutions?

Now I'm using Firebase Cloud Functions to generate .docx (the same I do on the client-side) and I want to be able to convert them to .pdf (both client and backend). Is this achievable? Is this scalable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [Firebase Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions) (which uses an underlying Cloud Function) with the [nodejs runtime](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/nodejs-runtime). But if you are not planning to run a Firebase App I would recommend you to use just a Cloud Function.

You can take a look at [this quickstart](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/quickstart-nodejs) to get an introduction. After that you can try to deploy your own function specifying your`gotenberg-js-client` dependency in the `package.json` file.

The only thing you need to decide is how will the function access to the file. I recommend to store the pdf files in a [Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage) bucket and use the [nodejs Cloud Storage client library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@google-cloud/storage) to access them from within your Cloud Function.

Comment: why this answer is marked as solution? it doesn't contain any useful information, nor actually answer to the question...