# How to pull Docker Hub image to Google Cloud Run?

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run, google-container-registry

I'm trying to pull Docker images into Google Cloud Run. I see that I would probably need to pull it first to Google Container registry, but can I somehow avoid it? Also, I'd rather have it straight from the source to have it up-to-date.

[image]

Comment: Can you use an ordinary Docker image name there; `thecodingmachine/gotenberg` or `docker.io/thecodingmachine/gotenberg`?  In spite of it being labeled "URL" the examples in the image aren't actually standard URLs.

Comment: Nope, no cigar here. Looks like they have specific requirements towards that

Comment: I think you need to push it first using to command ```docker push gcr.io/project-name/image-name:version.0``` then try to select it ```gcr.io/project-name/image-name:version``` to see what happened

Comment: I'm afraid it is impossible, according to https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/deploying#images it supports only Google Container Registry or Google Artifact Registry

Comment: Check also "Deploying images from unsupported registries" part https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/deploying#other-registries

Comment: @jeand'arme, don't try it, I already tried when I saw [your post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66269206/converting-docx-to-pdf-using-gotenberg-and-google-cloud). I pull the image locally and push it to GCR. But at the end, even if I deployed on Cloud Run, with the correct port set, there is a runtime issue because a directory is created at root path (/tiny). This container can't run on Cloud Run, today....

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere dang, it's strange. It should be working by definition and if it can't run normal Docker image then I think Google engineers should take a look into it.

Comment: Are there any other solutions to that problem then?

Comment: It's an open source project. I put it in my todo to have a look on it, it's an interesting case.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

I got a look on the project and finally I successfully run it on Cloud Run

Firstly, you can't pull image outside [Google Container Registry](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry) or [Artifact Registry](https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry). So you need to pull the image, tag it and push it in GCP (your project or not, but on GCP)

Here the steps

```
# Pull the image (I did it on Cloud Shell)
docker pull thecodingmachine/gotenberg:6

# Tag the image
docker tag thecodingmachine/gotenberg:6 gcr.io/<MY_PROJECT_ID>/thecodingmachine/gotenberg:6

#Push the image (no authentication issue on Cloud Shell)
docker push gcr.io/<MY_PROJECT_ID>/thecodingmachine/gotenberg:6

# Deploy on Cloud Run
gcloud run deploy --image=gcr.io/<MY_PROJECT_ID>/thecodingmachine/gotenberg:6 \
  --port=3000 --region=us-central1 --allow-unauthenticated --platform=managed \
  --command=gotenberg gotenberg
```

The trick on the Cloud Run deployment is:

- You need to specify the port, not use the default 8080, it's the 3000 here
- You need to specify the command explicitly. By default, the entrypoint is used (the `/tini`) and the container should be not well built because there is permission issue. More detail in the [Dockerfile](https://github.com/thecodingmachine/gotenberg/blob/master/build/package/Dockerfile)

So then, use the Cloud Run URL instead of the `http://localhost:3000` that you have in the documentation and enjoy!

Comment: Wow! Will implement it right after I get up tomorrow - thank you!

Comment: I don't think there's an issue with `tini` on Cloud Run. `tini` should work just fine.

Comment: @AhmetB-Google yes, it should work. The dockerfile perform a `chmod +x` and I don't know why I get a `terminated: Application failed to start: Failed to create init process: failed to load /tini: permission denied` in the Cloud Run logs when I don't specify the `command` parameter. You can have a try on it.

Comment: Works! Thank you so much.

Comment: For those that need it (for example, not using cloud shell, but from a workstation), to authenticate to GCR from the CLI, use `gcloud auth configure-docker`

Comment: Anybody know how to modify last command after "#Deploy on Cloud Run"?
I would like to run seq on Google Cloud Run.

# Pull the image - OK 
# Tag the image - OK 
# Push the image - OK 
**# Deploy on Cloud Run - NEED A HELP WITH COMMAND**
 
`docker run --name seq -d --restart unless-stopped -e ACCEPT_EULA=Y -p 5341:80 datalust/seq:latest`

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere so there is again the same problem, but with version 7. Can I please ask you to just peek into it? https://github.com/gotenberg/gotenberg/issues/505

Comment: But [not all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77594027/why-do-images-like-cloudnativelabs-whats-my-ip-not-run-on-cloud-run) Docker Hub images run on Cloud Run.

Comment: Sure, not all images. Cloud Run runtime contract must be enforced https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/container-contract

Answer (score 27):

Google has updated the Cloud Run setup and now supports Docker Hub images out of the box. Simply add your repo path (+ tag if you want) without any region/host and it will be pulled from Docker Hub.

[image: use Docker Hub image in Google Cloud Run]

Comment: So just have Dockerfile or .yaml file in your repo and it's all good?

Comment: No, the image needs to be hosted on dockerhub.com, then you can do what I described here. With the Dockerfile you can create an image using the `docker build` command. This image can be pushed to a container-registry like DockerHub.

Comment: please explain the formatting for this? eg. I have this for my Grafana image: "docker.io/grafana/grafana-oss"

Comment: The link you posted doesn't work, but the image can be found on docker-hub here: https://hub.docker.com/r/grafana/grafana-oss. To use it in "Google Cloud Run", simply enter `grafana/grafana-oss` into the input field, or if you want to use a specific version, then enter something like `grafana/grafana-oss:9.5.12`

Comment: But not all the images run on Cloud Run. E.g. [`tomthetommy/whatsmyip`](https://hub.docker.com/r/tomthetommy/whatsmyip) does. [`cloudnativelabs/whats-my-ip`](https://hub.docker.com/r/cloudnativelabs/whats-my-ip) though runs locally under `docker`, but not on Cloud Run. I guess something's wrong with the executable file (`/home/server`). I think so because I created a new image with the executable and it still doesn't run. It's either `/home/server: line 1: syntax error: unexpected "("` or `terminated: Application failed to start: failed to load /home/server: exec format error`.

Comment: More on it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77594027/why-do-images-like-cloudnativelabs-whats-my-ip-not-run-on-cloud-run).