# Why do images like `cloudnativelabs/whats-my-ip` not run on Cloud Run?

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run, dockerhub

I tried to run [`cloudnativelabs/whats-my-ip`](https://hub.docker.com/r/cloudnativelabs/whats-my-ip) on GCP (Cloud Run), but it failed:

> /home/server: line 1: syntax error: unexpected "(" 
> Container called exit(2).

The image contains a Go program, but this looks like it tries to run it as a script. Because there's no syntax when you run a binary.

What's happening here? Why does it fail? Does it really think the entrypoint is a script? A shell script? Why?

Is this a duplicate of the [`exec format error`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42494853/standard-init-linux-go178-exec-user-process-caused-exec-format-error)? No, at least the message is different. And as far as I can tell architectures on Docker Hub and Cloud Run match.

Steps to reproduce:

```
resource "google_cloud_run_v2_service" "cloud-run-test" {
    name = "cloud-run-test"
    location = "europe-central2"
    template {
        containers {
            image = "cloudnativelabs/whats-my-ip"
        }
    }
}
```

```
$ terraform init
$ terraform apply
$ gcloud logging read 'logName:projects/PROJECT_ID/logs/run.googleapis.com%2F' --format 'text(logName, textPayload, timestamp)' --project PROJECT_ID
---
log_name:     projects/PROJECT_ID/logs/run.googleapis.com%2Fvarlog%2Fsystem
text_payload: Container called exit(2).
timestamp:    2023-12-09T03:40:23.628609204Z
---
log_name:     projects/PROJECT_ID/logs/run.googleapis.com%2Fstderr
text_payload: /home/server: line 1: syntax error: unexpected "("
timestamp:    2023-12-09T03:40:22.632415Z
```

I moved my experiments with the image to [this gist](https://gist.github.com/x-yuri/c99237fa0980f540b24ab17c5a7e8e79).

Comment: Have you tried this image on local machine? Are you able to succeed? Or you are getting same error?

Comment: @RoopaM I forgot to mention it. Locally the image works. And I believe the architecture on Docker Hub, Cloud Run and locally matches (`linux/amd64`).

Comment: Can you share your `cloud run` configurations?

Comment: Did you build the container or are you using their image directly?

Comment: @RoopaM I provisioned the following [`terraform` project](https://gist.github.com/x-yuri/cb058888a54e3deef4d5fda646080914). Does that answer your question? If not, be more specific please.

Comment: @JohnHanley Using the Docker Hub image directly. Which [should work](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75640854/52499). Also see my previous comment.

Comment: Edit your post and show everything we need to duplicate your problem. Dockerfile, gcloud command, etc.

Comment: Is there a missing shebang line? That was the cause of a similar error: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/45781/shell-script-fails-syntax-error-unexpected If you copy /home/server out of the image, what does a tool like `file` say about it?

Comment: @JohnHanley done

Comment: @NickODell It's a `go` program. See the updated question.

Comment: It seems odd that `file` reports this is a 32-bit executable. All of the other compiled go programs I can find are reported as `ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), statically linked`. Maybe it's really a 32-bit build, despite being labeled as a 64-bit build. But then why would it fail in Cloud Run, but not locally? Not sure.

Comment: @NickODell The image was built 7 years ago. That might explain the 32-bit part. Despite being labeled? Do you mean the `linux/amd64` part? Maybe there's no `amd32` on Docker Hub? At least I don't see it [here](https://docs.docker.com/build/building/multi-platform/). And I've confirmed, Cloud Run tries to do `sh /home/server` for some reason. See the updated question. Apparently `docker` (locally) runs it somewhat differently than `kubernetes` I guess (on Cloud Run).

Comment: @NickODell I tried to run a 32-bit binary on Cloud Run and... it seems like Cloud Run doesn't expect 32-bit binaries, and falls back to `sh` (`sh /path/to/executable`). Although there are still some details that alone doesn't explain.

Comment: **Executables in the container image must be compiled for Linux 64-bit. Cloud Run specifically supports the Linux x86_64 ABI format.** https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/container-contract

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not exactly the reason (depends on your definition) but this is as close as I could probably hope to get. According to the [fragment of the docs](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/container-contract) John Hanley [quoted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77617687/why-do-images-like-cloudnativelabs-whats-my-ip-not-run-on-cloud-run/77634340#comment136861486_77617687):

> Executables in the container image must be compiled for Linux 64-bit. Cloud Run specifically supports the Linux x86_64 ABI format.

```
$ docker container create cloudnativelabs/whats-my-ip
$ docker cp 97bd786fbc2dd1df6925121ae8c0febebaf1a6f8785c10a7a7237e5799791289:/home/server /tmp/server
$ docker rm 97bd786fbc2dd1df6925121ae8c0febebaf1a6f8785c10a7a7237e5799791289

$ file /tmp/server
/tmp/server: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), statically linked, Go BuildID=edc3254ee8543cb3d51767295b041bc44368d286, with debug_info, not stripped
```

The reason is apparently because `/home/server` is a 32-bit binary.